# Reduce Multidimensional Array of Numbers

Tags: javascript

How can I find the sum of all the numbers in the following multidimensional array by the [Array.prototype.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) function:

```
var arr = [["one",3],["five",15],["ten",30],["twenty",40]];
```

I know how to do that using for loop, but just wondering...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can do it like this,

```
var sum = [["one",3],["five",15],["ten",30],["twenty",40]].reduce(function(a,b){
  return a + b[1];
}, 0);
```

In the above code, 0 passed as a second argument is the initial value to be used in the calculation.

Comment: thanx... I forgot the 0, that's why it returned NaN in my case.

Comment: MDN didn't help me understand how .reduce worked with 2d arrays, but this example did...  b[1], (is 3, next its 15, then 30, then 40)  as the value added to accumulator and returned.

Answer (score 1):

Break this down into sub-problems.

First, write `getNumbers` to get an array of numbers from the input.
It uses `getNumber`, which get the second element in each little array.
`sum` adds up the numbers in an array using `reduce`,
which uses the `add` function to add two numbers

```js
function sum(arr)        { return arr.reduce(add, 0); }
function add(a, b)       { return a + b; }
function getNumber(pair) { return pair[1]; }
function getNumbers(arr) { return arr.map(getNumber); }

var arr = [["one",3],["five",15],["ten",30],["twenty",40]];

console.log(sum(getNumbers(arr)));
```

Comment: your code seems that we require 2 different iterations to achieve what OP wanted. 1) for map 2) for reduce. Why is that? any specific reasons?

Comment: Right, it's called decomposing the problem.